# How can I increase the amount of time the Typing animation is shown in web chat?

Tags: botframework

When my bot has multiple lines to say between texts, I want to display the typing indicator. I'm using `ActivityTypes.Typing`, but in webchat (and the emulator) is disappears so fast I can't even see it. In Teams is sticks around for a little longer but not much. Is there a way to set an amount of time to have the animation appear for, or at least a method to make it last longer? In my code I'm sending it as a discrete activity like this:

```js
async getEmployeeTitle(step) {
    await step.context.sendActivity('OK, first I will need some additional information about the employee.');
    await step.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
    return await step.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, `What is the employee's **Job Title**?`);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Web Chat v4.5, there is no way to set the typing indicator duration; however, in v4.6 which should be released towards the end of the month, you can set the typing indicator duration in Web Chat's style options.

**Web Chat v4**

```js
const styleOptions = {
  typingAnimationDuration: 5000
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
     directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
     styleOptions
  },
  document.getElementById('webchat')
);
```

By default, Web Chat displays the typing indicator for [5000 milliseconds](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/b2104dfbcf191118a40290bf276d6de48269030a/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js#L139) or until it receives another activity from the bot. If you wanted to add more time between activities, I would recommend adding a delay between sending activities.

**BotFramework SDK v4 (Node)**

```js
async getEmployeeTitle(step) {
    await step.context.sendActivity('OK, first I will need some additional information about the employee.');
    await step.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
    await context.sendActivity({ type: 'delay', value: 3000 });  // Delay 3000 milliseconds
    return await step.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, `What is the employee's **Job Title**?`);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to set those options via native webchat? I'm not using direct line.

Comment: Actually, you can just ignore the top part if not using direct line, I see that now. The second code block works perfectly. Adding delays *as an Activity* doesn't work because it cancels the typing action. By adding the `await new Promise` line, that allows typing to play out. I just need 2-3 seconds, so just delaying the next activity via this method was all I needed.