# is there a way to configure how often is the typing activity generated and sent to bot by using sendTypingIndicator={true} in the WebChat

Tags: botframework, web-chat

When webchat has sendTypingIndicator={true}, and a user types in the input text box of chat, I have noticed, every **3s** a new "typing" Activity is sent. Is there a way to configure this duration and increase it to something longer delay in 2 typing activities?

```
 window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
      {
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
        ***sendTypingIndicator: true,*** // any way to increase the delay in 2 typing activities??
        store
      },
      document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
```

Comment: what is your version of Web Chat ? V4 0r V4.6 and above ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I increase the amount of time the Typing animation is shown in web chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330388/how-can-i-increase-the-amount-of-time-the-typing-animation-is-shown-in-web-chat)

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth, that link discusses how to change the look and feel of the displayed typing indicator when a typing activity arrives from the bot. For instance, changing the three dots ('...') to a spinning wheel or adjusting the height, etc. It doesn't affect the typing activity sent from user to bot when 'sendTypingIndicator' is set to `true`.

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth - the questionn you linked is for showing the typing animation on webchat. My question is for activities sent from the webchat by the user to the Bot.

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth- I am using "version": "4.12.1" of botframework webchat

Comment: As per your question “ Is there a way to configure this duration” that’s why I have given the solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, and this is by design. Setting 'sendTypingIndicator' to `true` means Web Chat is actively checking if a user is typing in the send box or not. If, for example, a delay of 3s was set on that property, then Web Chat would not be able to tell if I only typed "Hi", which would take less than 1s to type. Consequently, it wouldn't send the typing indicator activity for another ~2.5s after I had already finished.

This would likely result in unusual experiences for the user.

Comment: Let me explain my quesn a little more, What i am saying is currently the web chat actively checks if a user is typing and sends the "Typing" activities with from="user" to the bot every 3s. So if a user typed just "Hi" which took suppose only 1sec. then only 1 Typing activity is sent to bot. if the user is typing for more than 9 seconds, 4 typing activities are sent to bot. (every 3seconds). But is there a way to make this interval of sending the activity to bot configurable as this 3 sec is by default.